# Is it a correct way to extend Material-UI components (React / Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to extend material-ui components as my own component with custom properties. I'm using reactjs w/ typescript.

The below code is my trial :

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
import Tabs, { TabsProps } from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';

export interface Iprops extends TabsProps {
  /* how to add a variant ? */
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
    root: {
       // styles
     }
}));

export const BasicTabs = (props: Iprops) => {
    const classes = useStyles(props);
    if (props.variant === 'test') {
        return (
            <Tabs
                {...props}
                className={clsx(classes.root, props.className)}
            />
        );
    }
    return (
        <Tabs {...props} />
    );
};
```

So, what Im trying to do now is return a custom styled button when the variant is 'test'.

So, my first question is 
**1. How to add a new variant to the button?**

the second question is 
**2. should I pass the children like**

```
<Tabs {...props}>{props.children}</Tabs>
```

all the time whenever I extend a material-ui components?

Answer (score 5):

```
import React from 'react'
import TextField, { StandardTextFieldProps } from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

/**
 * Extend properties
 */
export interface PasswordProps extends StandardTextFieldProps {
    custom: string
}

/**
 * Password input
 * @param props Properties
 */
export const PasswordField: React.FunctionComponent<PasswordProps> = (props) => {
    props = Object.assign({ type: 'password' }, props)
    return (
        <TextField {...props}>
            {props.children}
        </TextField>
    )
}
```

For your questions:
A. Extend the props, add variants to the interface you want.
B. Yes, always like this as suggested with React official 'composition model' https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html